# Change component state form another component rendered in a v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of components rendered in a a v-for. I want to set the "show" Boolean property as false in the other components when one of them is set to true:
To simplify I am only adding two components

Main component code:

```
<template>
    <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <section class="sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
                <nav-bar-user-profile-item></nav-bar-user-profile-item>
                <nav-bar-item></nav-bar-item>
                <nav-bar-item></nav-bar-item>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
import NavBarUserProfileItem from '@/components/NavBar/NavBarUserProfileItem';
import NavBarItem from '@/components/NavBar/NavBarItem';

export default {
    name: 'NavBar',
    components: {
        NavBarUserProfileItem,
        NavBarItem
    },
    methods: {
        MenuHasBeenToggled(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }
}
```

NavBarItemComponent

```
<template>
    <li class="treeview2 item" :class="{'menu-open': isOpen, 'active': menu.active}" @click="ToggleState">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
            <span>{{ menu.title }}</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <collapse-transition>
            <ul class="treeview-menu" v-show="isOpen">
                <li v-for="submenu in menu.submenus" :key="submenu.title" :class="{'active': (('active' in submenu) ? submenu.active : false)}">
                    <b-link :href="submenu.link">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                        {{ submenu.title }}
                    </b-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </collapse-transition>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    
    export default {
        name: 'NavBarItem',
        data: function () {
            return {
                isOpen: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            
        },
        methods: {
            ToggleState() {
                this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
                this.$emit("toggle-state");
            }
        },
        props: {
            menu: {
                type: Object,
                default: function() {
                    return {
                        link: "#",
                        title: "Main menu",
                        active: true,
                        submenus: [
                            {
                                link: "#",
                                title: "Submenu 1",
                            },
                            {
                                link: "#",
                                title: "Submenu 2",
                                active: true
                            },
                            {
                                link: "#",
                                title: "Submenu 3",
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    
</style>
```

The goal is to click on one of the  and show the menu contents while at the same time collapse the other components.

I thought about using an array of variables and bind it to the "show" prop and with an event listen to it and set every variable to false except the one form the component that sent the event.

How can I know which component sent the event?

Any better idea on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the best way to do it is to add a uniuque identifier property to each NavBarItem and a property for a selected NavBarItem. Then in the main component you can on click on NavBarItem set selected NavBarItem and in NavBarItem make the isOpen computed on the basis if current NavBarItem identifier equals the clicked NavBarItem. Something like this:

```
<template>
    <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <section class="sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
                <nav-bar-user-profile-item></nav-bar-user-profile-item>
                <nav-bar-item item-id="1" :selected-item-id="selectedNavbarItemId" @click="selectedNavBarItemId = 1"></nav-bar-item>
                <nav-bar-item item-id="2" :selected-item-id="selectedNavbarItemId" @click="selectedNavBarItemId = 2"></nav-bar-item>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
import NavBarUserProfileItem from '@/components/NavBar/NavBarUserProfileItem';
import NavBarItem from '@/components/NavBar/NavBarItem';

export default {
    name: 'NavBar',
    components: {
        NavBarUserProfileItem,
        NavBarItem
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
             selectedNavBarItemId: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        MenuHasBeenToggled(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }
}
```

And in NavBarItem

```
<template>
    <li class="treeview2 item" :class="{'menu-open': isOpen, 'active': menu.active}" @click="ToggleState">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
            <span>{{ menu.title }}</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <collapse-transition>
            <ul class="treeview-menu" v-show="isOpen">
                <li v-for="submenu in menu.submenus" :key="submenu.title" :class="{'active': (('active' in submenu) ? submenu.active : false)}">
                    <b-link :href="submenu.link">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
                        {{ submenu.title }}
                    </b-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </collapse-transition>
    </li>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'NavBarItem',
        data: function () {
            return {

            }
        },
        computed: {
           isOpen:function(){
               return itemId == selectedItemId;
           }
        },
        methods: {

        },
        props: {
            itemId:Number,
            selectedItemId:Number,
            menu: {
                type: Object,
                default: function() {
                    return {
                        link: "#",
                        title: "Main menu",
                        active: true,
                        submenus: [
                            {
                                link: "#",
                                title: "Submenu 1",
                            },
                            {
                                link: "#",
                                title: "Submenu 2",
                                active: true
                            },
                            {
                                link: "#",
                                title: "Submenu 3",
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Instead of using the @click event on the component i used a custom event emitted from it to the parent component to set the value, since the click was not reactive. Cool